# How to pass the value in the middle of the get method url in angular

Tags: angular

This is my login model

Login.ts:

```
export class Login{
    access_token : string;
    token_type : string;
    expires_in : string;
    refresh_token : string;
    FirstName : string;
    LastName : string;
    Email : string;
    AccountNo : string;
    client_Id : string;
}
```

After the user login.I want to use  [this] value of the account no from login model in the middle of the below url in service file to get the customer details.

Checkout.service.ts:

```
login:Login[]


        async getAddress() {
            const address = await this.httpClient.get<Customer[]>('http://localhost:49456/api/customer/' + '{{login.AccountNo}}' +'/profile/', { withCredentials: true })
                .toPromise();
            return address;
        }
```

I tried to get the values using binding but not get the customer details.How to achieve this.

checkout.ts:

```
 customer:Customer[];

  async ngOnInit() {

    const address = <Customer[]>await this.checkoutService.getAddress();
    if (address) {
      this.customer = address;
    }
    console.log(this.customer);
}
```

html:

```
<div *ngFor ="let cust of customer">
                          <input type="radio"> &nbsp;<span><b>{{cust.FirstName}} {{cust.LastName}}  &nbsp; {{customer.Telephone}}</b></span>
</div
```

Comment: Why are you using binding? You can just use `+ login.AccountNo`

Comment: Already use like this but it dot the return the accountno value

Comment: What do you want it to return?

Comment: I want to return the account no value in the above url to get the customer details

Comment: How you populate the values to login model? if possible add that code as well.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand the problem? `'http://localhost:49456/api/customer/' + login.AccountNo +'/profile/'`

Comment: I want to pass the account no value in the url

Comment: Okay, and if you use the code I pasted above, what does it give you?

Comment: In template file using binding I got the values from login model.But dn't knw how to pass the value in url@codeninja.sj

Comment: Account no is unique for customer.Using Account no value i want to fetch the customer details@user184994

Comment: vino, have you tried @user184994 solution?

Comment: I've just seen that `login` is an array. How do you know which one you want?

Comment: Yeah.i tried By passing only one account no value in the url.@user184994

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but how do you know *which* account no value to use if you have an array?

Comment: In template using ngFor loop i can fetch the values.But dn't know how to pass the value in url in service file

Comment: How is `getAddress` called? Is it called from the HTML template? It would make this a lot easier if you could provide more of the code.

Comment: Ok. Updated the code

Comment: getAddress() is jst a variable assign@user184994